# How do i write my own pre-save transform?

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

As described [here](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Automatic_conversion_of_wikitext), the mediawiki parser allows for a pre-save transform which will automatically replace wikitext with something else.

How do I create my own?

I did find this, but I can't even be sure it's relevant anymore.
http://mediawiki.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.13.3/classArticle_a0d27b9b92f688ea124b1f1c4c0b60018.html

Comment: I found this: https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classParserOptions.html#a2ced2f42de1293310d968a235766c729 Now I just need to figure out how to use it.

Comment: Apparently that's just a boolean :(

Answer (score 2):

In modern MediaWiki versions (v1.21+), one way to do this could be to:

1. Write your own [ContentHandler](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ContentHandler) classes, extending [WikiTextContent](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classWikitextContent.html) and [WikitextContentHandler](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classWikitextContentHandler.html).  These could be as simple as:

   ```php
   class MyContentHandler extends WikitextContentHandler {
       protected function getContentClass() {
           return 'MyContent';
       }
   }
   class MyContent extends WikitextContent {
       // TODO: override preSaveTransform() here
   }
   ```
2. In the Content subclass, override the [preSaveTransform()](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classWikitextContent.html#ae8b69647c7b1a36511d6b78a802b3297) method, e.g. like this (if you want to modify the wikitext after the normal PST pass):

   ```php
   public function preSaveTransform( Title $title, User $user, ParserOptions $popts ) {
       $content = parent::preSaveTransform( $title, $user, $popts );
       $orig = $text = $content->getNativeData();
       // ...modify $text here...
       return ( $orig === $text ) ? $content : new static( $text );
   }
   ```
3. Register your new ContentHandler as the handler for ordinary wiki pages using [$wgContentHandlers](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgContentHandlers) in LocalSettings.php:

   ```php
   $wgContentHandlers[CONTENT_MODEL_WIKITEXT] = 'MyContentHandler';
   ```

(Warning: I believe this method should work, but I have not actually tested it!  Use at your own risk.  Improvements and bug reports welcome.)

Answer (score 1):

The replacement of the signature is [hard-coded in mediawiki/core](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/cf08f986af0a1cfa092f46f5c772c610fb52dce4/includes/parser/Parser.php#L4846-L4850).

I don't know any way to do the same thing without changing core files (which, btw, isn't a good idea). You could use a [parser function](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parser_functions) or create a [tag extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Tag_extensions) to achieve what you want to do in a similar way.

Comment: What I am doing requires a pre-save transformation, it wouldn't just be a convenience. Now that i know doing what I wanted is impossible, I will probably create a more general question for my actual goal to see if there is an alternative solution.